# regular expression - return a string

Tags: php, regex

I'm very bad at regular expressions, can anybody help me on it?

I have product description in var **$desc** , something like this:

```
some text , some text, some text , some text
some text , some text , some text , some text
Product sku: 111111
some text , some text, some text , some text
```

What I need is to return a number after text "***Product sku:***". How to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried something or did some research ?

Comment: Please post your attempt that isn't working.  That would be the first step so people can help tweak what you already have.

Comment: I did nothing cause have no idea how to realize it.

Comment: Some question before I answer: SKU would always be a number? It would be in 3rd line always? No other detail will be mentioned in SKU line?

Comment: Yes, it is ALWAYS nubber and it ALWAYS after "Product SKU:"

Comment: But i don't know in witch line it will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, to match against any regular expression, we use `preg_match`, `preg_match_all` functions:

```
<?php
preg_match('/Product sku:[\s]*([\d]+)/i', 'some text , some text, some text , some text
some text , some text , some text , some text
Product SKU: 111111
some text , some text, some text , some text', $matches);
print_r($matches);

/**
Output:
Array ( [0] => Product SKU: 111111 [1] => 111111 ) // $matches[1] is what you need
*/

?>
```

> Note `i` in regular expression which is for case-insensitivity. So
>   that it matches both `sku` & `SKU`

You can read more about this function here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: Thenks , it help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$subject = "some text , some text, some text , some text
some text , some text , some text , some text
Product sku: 111111 dhgfh
some text , some text, some text , some text";

$pattern = '/Product sku:\s*(?P<product_sku>\d+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);


if (isset($matches['product_sku'])) {
    echo 'Product sku: ' . $matches['product_sku'];
}
else {
    echo 'Product sku not found!';
}
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/hO4bT5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code:

```
if(preg_match('/Product sku:\s*?(\d+)/mi',$strs,$matchs)){                                                                                                    
    echo $matchs[1];
}
```

Hope this can help you！